# Molecular structure of all periodic table element molecules exceptional cases etc

Tags: molecules, elements, reference-request

I am searching about some basics in chemistry. I was looking for the molecular structure of all periodic table element molecules.
eg: Hydrogen molecule: as $\ce{H2}$; structure:[image]

I was able to find out several others too. But when I reach to certain molecules like $\ce{He}$ I was not able to find out the structure. 
Does anyone know from where I can get the molecular structure of all periodic table elements. And if not, could you please explain the case of Helium and other noble gases. I am very poor in chemistry. Anyone showing me a reference on how to find the answer is welcome. Thanks in advance, and Happy New Year to all... :)

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! Had you any questions about the workings of the site, visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help), or you can just take a little [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) about how chem.SE works. I added the "reference request" tag so that your question doesn't get many downvotes. [This link](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) shows how good questions are asked. I recommend you take a look at what's written there.

Comment: 1. All elements do not form "molecules", with itself, necessarily 2.Helium and other "noble gases" are unreactive (cannot form molecules under normal conditions)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

The noble gases (group $18$) are rather inert, so their molecule is just a single atom.

The following elements **usually** consist of molecules made up of two atoms: $\ce{H2}$, $\ce{N2}$, $\ce{O2}$, $\ce{F2}$, $\ce{Cl2}$, $\ce{Br2}$, $\ce{I2}$.

Astatine ($\ce{At}$) should also belong to that list but it is not confirmed because of its short half-life.

Sulfur exists as ($\ce{S8}$); phosphorus exists as ($\ce{P4}$).

The structure of boron ($\ce{B}$), arsenic ($\ce{As}$), selenium ($\ce{Se}$), antimony ($\ce{Sb}$), and tellurium ($\ce{Te}$) are rather complicated.

Carbon ($\ce{C}$) has too many forms, but its most common forms are graphite and diamond, which is demonstrated below.

Silicon ($\ce{Si}$) and germanium ($\ce{Ge}$) both assume the structure of diamond.

Metals all adopt a metallic structure. Read more [here](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/atoms/structures/metals.html).

---

### Further

You might go to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allotropy) to learn about the elements I skipped.

---

### Gallery

Sulfur:

[image]

Phosphorus:

[image]

Carbon (as graphite):

[image]

The common structure of diamond, silicon, and germanium (left diamond, right graphite):

[image]

---

Credits:

All images are from Wikipedia.

Comment: Please do not use links to images on the web. Instead upload them to the sites contracted hoster. Before you do that, make sure you are allowed to use the image, i.e. can you redistribute it under [creative commons by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and **always give proper credit to the original source**.  For example: [Can I upload it to my site?
Electronic redistribution is strictly prohibited. ](https://www.ptable.com/about.html) Please fix your post accordingly, otherwise I am forced to delete it.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Sorry, please give me a moment.

Comment: Also note that this is a [tag:reference-request]. Please refer to a (or more) publications to read up on.